# Meteor: Exception in template helper

Tags: meteor

This code in Meteor.

```
Template.message.helpers({
    message: function() {
        var message = Messages.findOne({ _id: FlowRouter.getParam('messageId')});
        var curTime = new Date();
        console.log(message.createdAt.getHours());

        return message;
    }
});
```

Gives me this exception:

```
Exception in template helper: message@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=0da6be4507e857f169e0cecb7b0874729eae4663:239:13
bindDataContext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3051:14
Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1715:14
wrapHelper/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3103:14
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
wrapHelper/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3102:12
Spacebars.dot@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:234:13
template.message.js/Template.message</<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=0da6be4507e857f169e0cecb7b0874729eae4663:85:31
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2086:20
viewAutorun/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934:18
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932:14
Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271:12
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931:12
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:229:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:613:11
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1944:14
Blaze._materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2080:5
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640:12
Blaze._materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2079:3
materializeDOMInner@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1532:9
Blaze._materializeDOM@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1474:3
Blaze._materializeDOM@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1483:7
Blaze._materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2113:25
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640:12
Blaze._materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2079:3
Blaze.render@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2370:3
_render@http://localhost:3000/packages/kadira_blaze-layout.js?hash=dbd1396d04e62378fc8792cdef18869a1108cedd:204:5
render/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/kadira_blaze-layout.js?hash=dbd1396d04e62378fc8792cdef18869a1108cedd:77:9
withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:1077:17
withoutInvocation/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:464:26
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:1105:17
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:401:11
  meteor.js:930:11
```

It actually gets printed twice but I felt it was large and unnecessary to show here twice.

And line 239 of app.js looks like this (it's line 7 here).

```
Template.message.helpers({                                                                            // 34
    message: function () {                                                                            // 35
        var message = Messages.findOne({                                                              // 36
            _id: FlowRouter.getParam('messageId')                                                     // 36
        });                                                                                           // 36
        var curTime = new Date();                                                                     // 37
        console.log(message.createdAt.getHours());                                                    // 38
        return message;                                                                               // 40
    }                                                                                                 // 41
```

But the hours still get printed to the console.

My goal is to use the createdAt date to subtract it from a current Date object and get a time delta. But I never got that far because whatever I try to do with message.createdAt produces this strange exception.

If I just do console.log(message.createdAt) I see TWO ISO formatted dates in the browser console, and two exceptions.

If I try something else like message.createdAt.getTime() I get one Unix timestamp.

What the heck is going on?

I was actually able to subtract the date and use it as intended, but the exceptions kept showing up in spite of the code working.

Comment: You see duplicates because the helper is running multiple times (due to reactive changes). What is `createdAt`, a JS Date object?

Comment: It's from a mongo collection, shows as ISODate in the mongo shell but I assume it's a Date object in JS. I can use some Date attributes like year and getTime() on it.

Comment: Are you waiting for the subscription to finish before rendering/calling that helper?

Comment: Thanks @chazsolo because you steered me in the right direction. I googled waiting for meteor subscription and found out about Template.subscriptionsReady which made me wrap my template in a conditional that only outputs my data if subscriptionsReady is true and that got rid of the exceptions. I now understand that the exceptions were coming each render until the data was ready. I'm new to meteor and this is my first project. Please make an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: `var date = message & message.createdAt; if(date) { console.log(new Date(date).getHours()); }` should stop giving you that error.

Comment: I'll have one for you soon, glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the errors is because the helper is being run, attempting to fetch data from a subscription that isn't ready yet. It eventually works because once the subscription *is* ready, the helper is re-run, and all is well. To fix this, simply wrap you helper with `Template.subscriptionsReady`:

```
<template name="message">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{message}}
  {{else}}
    {{> SomeLoadingTemplate}}
  {{/if}
</template>
```

> **NOTE:** This template will execute the `message` helper only when all
>   template-level subscriptions are "Ready" and instead will show a
>   loader template executing the else part.

---

Regarding a comment on the question, to wrap your logic with `if (date) {...}`: this will get rid of the error, but isn't really solving the problem. The helper is still being run multiple times when it doesn't have to. It seems to be a bit of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to hide potential errors like this.

Answer (score -1):

you have a template, a helper, and a local variable all called "message". even if that's not the source of your error, i'd gently suggest making them all different names.

Comment: would the person who downvoted me explain why this is bad advice?